# g:textField return null when g:form is submitted by g:link

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a g:textField as part of the g:form,

```
 <g:textField name="product"/>
```

when the g:form is submited by submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

My grails controller can get its value fine

```
def product = params.product
```

However, once I submit the g:form with g:link

```
<g:link url="[action:'submitData',controller:'dataController']" id="${book.name}">Submit</g:link>
```

Then

```
def product = params.product
```

will return null.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `g:link` is essentially nothing more than an `a` tag which is just a simple link. Links are unaware of the contents of the form and can only perform `GET` requests.  If you look at the HTTP request being made in your browser's console, you will notice that no form data is being passed. If you really need to use a link, you could use JavaScript to either update the `href` attribute of the tag, or determine the link when pressed and handle the navigation through JavaScript.